# align table inside table on the top

Tags: tables

I have sub-tables inside a table and I want that the text of the sub-tables is on the top of the row like on the second image.

[image: Example]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\listingsymbol}{\textbullet\thinspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|X|}
\hline
item 0 &  \begin{tabular}[x]{@{\listingsymbol}l@{}}
item 1\\
item 2\\
\end{tabular}
& \begin{tabular}[x]{@{\listingsymbol}l@{}}
item 1 \\
item 2\\
item 3\\
\end{tabular} & 
\begin{tabular}[x]{@{\listingsymbol}p{139pt}@{}}
item 1\\
item 2\\
item 3.1 \newline item 3.2\\
item 4\\    
\end{tabular} \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional argument to `tabular` is the 'anchor' of the `tabular`. I don't think `x` does anything, but `t`(op) does what you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\listingsymbol}{\textbullet\thinspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|X|}
\hline
item 0 &  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\listingsymbol}l@{}}
item 1\\
item 2\\
\end{tabular}
& \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\listingsymbol}l@{}}
item 1 \\
item 2 \\
item 3 \\
\end{tabular} & 
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\listingsymbol}p{139pt}@{}}
item 1 \\
item 2 \\
item 3.1 \newline
item 3.2 \\
item 4\\    
\end{tabular} \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```